# Enable a software MIDI output for use with pygame

Tags: python, kde, midi

I want to be able to play MIDI notes from the pygame.midi module, similar to Windows. I believe this means setting up some sort of software/virtual MIDI out device. Fluidsynth appears to be able to do what I need, but I'm not sure how to configure it. I am using KDE Neon.

Edit: Here is how I would set up MIDI with Pygame normally.

```
from pygame import midi
midi.init()
t=midi.Output(midi.get_default_output_id())
```

Comment: what is your specific question?

Comment: @jsotola In the end, how to use the Pygame.midi module for output on Linux with no MIDI hardware. However, I figured asking for a general soft MIDI device would solve more problems with other software that can play MIDI on windows, but not by default on Linux because it relies on a soft device.

Answer (score 0):

You should first make sure that **the kernel is appropriately configured**. (provision is made for necessary drivers), and that things were appropriately configured for your user.
Under whatever terminal, fire `amidi-l`, a couple of devices should be list. Like on mine :

```
acoswt@Tux ~ $ amidi -l
Dir Device    Name
IO  hw:1,0    Virtual Raw MIDI (16 subdevices)
IO  hw:1,1    Virtual Raw MIDI (16 subdevices)
IO  hw:1,2    Virtual Raw MIDI (16 subdevices)
IO  hw:1,3    Virtual Raw MIDI (16 subdevices)
IO  hw:2,0    M Audio Audiophile 24/96 MIDI
```

Then, you are correct, you'll need some software synthetizer like *fluidsynth*. So just install it (together with whatever sf2 compatible soundfount, preferably at least some general midi compatible font).
I suggest you also install [qsynth](https://qsynth.sourceforge.io/) (a gui that will ease your experience on fluidsynth)

Then after having launched fluidsynth, then your pygame, you'll have to use [aconnect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/aconnect) to connect some pygame midi output port (obtain the port number thanks to `aplaymidi -l`) to some fluidsynth midi input port. (obtain port number thanks to `arecordmidi` -l)

Of course, since you'll be playing with alsa directly, I warmly suggest not to be polluted by any sort of sound server.

Comment: This sounds like other stuff I was finding, but is complete. Okay, thanks. Will try. I’m not sure what a “sound server” is. Is JACK one of those?

Comment: @TheLabCat : You are correct. Jack is a sound server… so is pulseaudio too.

Comment: amidi -l is turning up a blank list. However, I can run fluidsynth -a alsa PINBALL.MID and get output,

Comment: @TheLabCat : That a good start. what do aplaymidi -l and arecordmidi -l output when fluidsynth and pygame are running ?

Comment: 14:0 is a MIDI through in both cases, and 128:0 is FLUID Synth (40349) as a playback.

Comment: I think you may misunderstand something about how I’m using Pygame…

Comment: @TheLabCat : Possibly ! And almost certainly. However, knowing that pygame.midi relies on *portmidi* there are just not many ways to instruct portmidi to output to a midi synth.